# Weird issue after installing BaseGameUtils

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-games

I have been trying to add BaseGameUtils to my game, but I have some issues with Grad.e

Upon adding the module, this line leads to a warning:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
```

Because the play-services-games is 8.1.0, as defined in the BaseGameUtils module. If I change the `play-services-ads` version to 8.1.0, the app compiles.

Since all the modules of play-services has to be the same version, how can I update `play-services-games` to 9.2.0? I tried to add the dependency, but it could not resolve it. I just updated the SDK, so the problem is not there.

---

If I add this line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

It causes OutOfMemoryException.

Removing `BaseGameUtils` and adding the dependencies to the main project works fine. Is there any way I can continue to keep BaseGameUtils and use 9.4.0(or newer)?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [build.gradle description](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) for Google Play Game services

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.4.0
```

instead of just only

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0
```

So your dependencies is look like this:

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.4.0'
compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}
```

For more information, check these [thread](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=23329#p95506) and [tutorial](https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio/).